# ngresource set global variable in success response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

i am running this code to run a REST request

```
app.factory('GetValidationsService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/Validations');
})
```

then calling it :

```
var global = 0;

GetValidationsService.get(
             function(data){
                        global = 3;
                 },
             function(err){
                  });

console.log(global);
```

result is  0 
and i would like it to be 3 .
how can i set value to be global in section ?

```
 function(data){
                            global = 3;
                     }
```

Comment: Did you try promise object. Please find it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Iamisti's answer would work since `$resource` don't return promises.
[See here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) :

> Note: In contrast to $http.config, promises are not supported in
>   $resource, because the same value would be used for multiple requests.

Yous should use the `$promise` property. 
Here is what would be his (and your ?) solution :

```
var global = 0;
var promise = GetValidationsService.get(function(data){
   global = 3;
}).$promise;

promise.then(function() {
     console.log(global);
});
```

Comment: @Iamisti yes, this is what I said in the answer ;) expect that I use the `$promise` property since `$resource` doesn't return promises.

Answer (score 0):

## problem

Since you perform an async action, your console will run sooner before you could change your variable.

## conclusion

So basically it does override your global variable but just after your promise resolved.

## validation

With the following way you can check your global variable after it's changed.

```
var global = 0;

var promise = GetValidationsService
                  .get(function(data){
                      global = 3;
                  }).$promise;

promise.then(function(){
    console.log(global);
});
```

Comment: `$resource` doesn't return a promise. You should use the `$promise` property. See my answer.